# .htaccess rule not excluding existing files when rule has a slash condition

Tags: .htaccess

I am redirecting this type of url

```
http://www.site.com/windows/games/ or http://www.site.com/windows/games
http://www.site.com/windows/software/ or http://www.site.com/windows/software
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/windows/ct.php?ct=games
http://www.site.com/windows/ct.php?ct=software
```

Site structure

```
wamp/www/Site/windows/ct.php
```

I am trying this way its redirecting properly but when url has trailing slash at end its rewriting css, js files too.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]*)/?$ /Site/windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
```

i.e

this type of url has css and javascript applied.

```
http://www.site.com/windows/games
```

but this type of url has no css and javascript applied. (not working with trailing slash).

```
http://www.site.com/windows/games/
```

I have tried several syntax like

```
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]+)/?$ /windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^windows/(^(.[^/]*)/?)$ /windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]*)/? /windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]+)/? /windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
```

but it didn't work.

Complete .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]*)/?$ /Site/windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/[^/]*/(.*\.html) /Site/error/400/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(error) - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/(.*?)\.xml$ rss/$1.php [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /Site/error/404/
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the absolute path for your css and js, if you have it like `="css/file.css"` u need to use `="http://domain.com/css/file.css"` you could use a rule to rewrite the css and js files but that would only work if all the css and js files are on the same folder always

Comment: @Prix Its working with absolute path but why its not working with relative path.

Comment: Because relative path assumes the closest folder as its root so when u use `domain.com/windows/games/` it takes games as the root folder.

Comment: @Prix I have all the css and js files in the same folder always, how to rewrite them.

Comment: @Prix I have css in `root/global/css/css.css` js in `root/global/js/js.js`

Comment: Could you share info on the relative paths and actual location of css/js files w.r.t your site structure?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I have css in `wamp/www/global/css/css.css` and js in `wamp/www/global/js/js.js`

Comment: ..and the relative paths that your htmls use to include them?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal relative path for css `../global/css/css.css`, relative path for js `../global/js/js.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your relative paths break when you add a trailing slash as it introduces two-levels of directory structure while the CSS/JS file paths come out only once `..`. So, your `RewriteRule` is actually firing for CSS/JS files as well when resolving 404s for paths like `/windows/global/js/js.js`. But, the scripts still fail to work because they aren't under `/Site` and that's where your rule is serving the request from.

So, to fix things without touching the relative URLs or resource locations; add another rule as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]*)/?$ /Site/windows/ct.php?ct=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^windows/(global/.*)$ /$1 [L] # handles css|js files
```

The rest of your `.htaccess` (of course) remains the same.

Comment: It is still same as before no css applied in trailing slash url's, Just tried your solution.

Comment: This works `RewriteRule ^windows/global/(.*)$ /Site/global/$1 [L] # handles css|js files`
`done a little tweeking to your solution and now it works. thanks

Comment: Oh, was your `global` directory inside `/www/Site`? I thought you said it was at `/www`. But, anyways.. glad you made it work :)

Comment: yes global was inside Site, I mistakenly told you this `wamp/www/global/` when it is `wamp/www/Site/global/`

Comment: Hi can you help me with this if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237604/htaccess-issue-with-full-site-switch-from-mobile-site?noredirect=1#comment37435343_24237604

Answer (score 0):

I use the following rule in .htaccess, but this may be too general:

```
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(\/?)$ /path/to/q.php?type=$1&q=$2&{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

This may be better for you:

```
RewriteRule ^windows(\/?)$ /path/to/windows.php?{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
RewriteRule ^windows/([^/]+)(\/?)$ /path/to/windows.php?type=$1&{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
```

You will have to change this according to your situation. I haven't tested this, but I hope it is good enough for you to get where you want.

Comment: It is same as before no css applied in trailing slash url's